# while use wp_signon( $creds, false ) get the error

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to login user automatically when user is activated in multisite.
but when I am trying to use `wp_signon()` it response with the error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\krosswall\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:127) in C:\xampp\htdocs\krosswall\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 955

I am trying to do this

```
function kw_activate_blogs( $user_id, $password, $meta ) {

    add_user_to_blog( '2', $user_id, get_site_option( 'default_user_role', 'subscriber' ) );

    $user = new WP_User( (int) $user_id );
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $user->user_login;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
    // safe redirect to actually login the user - otherwise they would need to manually refresh the page
    // PLUS: this clears the activation confirmation page with the plain text password printed on screen
    //wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
        exit;
    }

}

add_action( 'wpmu_activate_user', 'kw_activate_blogs', 10, 3 );
```

I added this code in `functions.php` file. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: run it before the headers and cookies are sent- 
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', kw_activate_blogs' );

Comment: i want to call it on 'wpmu_activate_user' hook...

Comment: can you demonstrate me how can i use it in my code??

Comment: if you want to use it with this hook try to add ob_start(); on the top of wp-config.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function kw_activate_blogs($user_id, $password, $meta)
{
    $result=add_user_to_blog('2', $user_id, get_site_option('default_user_role', 'subscriber'));
    if (!is_wp_error($result))
    {
        wp_set_current_user($user_id);
        if (wp_validate_auth_cookie() == FALSE)
        {
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true, false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //do something here on error
    }
}
```

You don't need their password in this case. You can also remove 2nd and 3rd arguments if you don't need `$meta` and change `add_action` to `add_action( 'wpmu_activate_user', 'kw_activate_blogs', 10);`

Comment: @piyush please do not forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. Glad I could help you.